# Does not implement interface error

Tags: c#-4.0

I have below C# code which I converted from Java. In this I am getting the error "does not implement inteface member System.Collections.IComparer.Comparer(object,obkject)"

Kindly help me to solve this error

```
internal class CompositeComparator : IComparer
{
    private IComparer major;
    private IComparer minor;
    public CompositeComparator(IComparer major, IComparer minor)
    {
        this.major = major;
        this.minor = minor;
    }
    public virtual int compare(object o1, object o2)
    {
        int result = major.Compare(o1, o2);
        if (result != 0)
        {
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return minor.Compare(o1, o2);
        }
    }
}

internal class ComparatorIStep : IComparer
{
    public ComparatorIStep()
    {
    }
    public virtual int compare(object o1, object o2)
    {
        int nReturn = ((LogMessage)o1).IStep - ((LogMessage)o2).IStep;
        return nReturn;
    }
}

internal class ComparatorType : IComparer
{
    public ComparatorType()
    {
    }
    public virtual int compare(object o1, object o2)
    {
        int nReturn = 0;

        LogMessage lm1 = (LogMessage)o1;
        LogMessage lm2 = (LogMessage)o2;
        bool b1 = lm1.isHeading;
        bool b2 = lm2.isHeading;
        if (b1 || !b2)
        {
            nReturn = -1;
        }
        else if (!b1 || b2)
        {
            nReturn = 1;
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: C# is case sensitive - change `compare` to `Compare`.

Answer (score 2):

IComparer has one method:

```
int Compare(
   object x,
   object y
);
```

It looks like you need to capitalize the c on "compare"

Answer (score 0):

You need to change line

```
public virtual int compare(object o1, object o2)
```

to

```
public virtual int Compare(object o1, object o2)
```

C# is case sensitive...

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem, but my solution was to add the public modifier to the method I had created:

Problem:

```
public class Ordenacao : IComparer<tab>
{
    int Compare(tab x, tab y)
    {
        tab a = (tab) x;
        tab b = (tab) y;
        return a.ordinal.CompareTo(b.ordinal);
    }
}
```

Solution:

```
public class Ordenacao : IComparer<tab>
{
    public int Compare(tab x, tab y)
    {
        tab a = (tab) x;
        tab b = (tab) y;
        return a.ordinal.CompareTo(b.ordinal);
    }
}
```

In both cases, mine and yours, I guess it was just an attention issue...